# Compile VxWorks project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tornado, vxworks

I have a VxWorks project that compiles under Toronado on my Win7 machine. I am trying to convert the same project to compile in my Visual Studio 2010. I don't need it to complete to where it creates a .o/out file but at least get through all the defines/includes and etc. so I can use Visual Studio's IDE for definition jumping and etc..
I'm at a point where I'm getting a 'undeclared identifier' for "_interrupt" which is included in several include files from the ..\tornado\target\config\ folder.

I'd appreciate any suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would like to comment on this but don't have enough points.

I do the same thing using eclipse instead of visual studio, I don't do anything special to make it work.

It sounds like you are trying to do the link even though you don't want to.  Make sure when you create your project you set it up to create a library not an executable, it should do the compile then but no linking.